# Adding page to ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created a ionic project with a single page, now I'm trying to add a new page called `about` using the command `ionic page about`but i'm getting `page is not a valid task`.
there's my terminal:

```
  cameraApp brill$ ionic page about
(node:2213) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
  _             _          
 (_)           (_)         
  _  ___  _ __  _  ___     
 | |/ _ \| '_ \| |/ __| 
 | | (_) | | | | | (__     
 |_|\___/|_| |_|_|\___|  CLI v2.0.0-beta.32

Usage: ionic task args


=======================
page is not a valid task


Available tasks: 
(use --help or -h for more info)


   start  ..........  Starts a new Ionic project in the specified PATH
   serve  ..........  Start a local development server for app dev/testing
   generate  .......  Generate pages and components
   platform  .......  Add platform target for building an Ionic app
   run  ............  Run an Ionic project on a connected device
   emulate  ........  Emulate an Ionic project on a simulator or emulator
   build  ..........  Build (prepare + compile) an Ionic project for a given platform.

   plugin  .........  Add a Cordova plugin
   resources  ......  Automatically create icon and splash screen resources (beta)
              Put your images in the ./resources directory, named splash or icon.
              Accepted file types are .png, .ai, and .psd.
              Icons should be 192x192 px without rounded corners.
              Splashscreens should be 2208x2208 px, with the image centered in the middle.

   upload  .........  Upload an app to your Ionic account
   share  ..........  Share an app with a client, co-worker, friend, or customer
   lib  ............  Gets Ionic library version or updates the Ionic library
   io  .............  Integrate your app with the ionic.io platform services (alpha)
   security  .......  Store your app's credentials for the Ionic Platform (alpha)
   push  ...........  Upload APNS and GCM credentials to Ionic Push (alpha)
   package  ........  Use Ionic Package to build your app (alpha)
   config  .........  Set configuration variables for your ionic app (alpha)
   service  ........  Add an Ionic service package and install any required plugins
   add  ............  Add an Ion, bower component, or addon to the project
   remove  .........  Remove an Ion, bower component, or addon from the project
   list  ...........  List Ions, bower components, or addons in the project
   info  ...........  List information about the users runtime environment
   help  ...........  Provides help for a certain command
   link  ...........  Sets your Ionic App ID for your project
   hooks  ..........  Manage your Ionic Cordova hooks
   state  ..........  Saves or restores state of your Ionic Application using the package.json file
   docs  ...........  Opens up the documentation for Ionic

ECENMBRJJCC:cameraApp brill$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is `ionic g page about`, you are just missing the g (which probably stands for generator). You can find more information in the [Ionic V2 documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/generate/).